# Java, Jackson Serialize/Deserialize Generic

Tags: java, jackson

With Jackson 2.6.7. I am trying to serialize/deserialize `Foo`.

```
public class Foo {
    @JsonProperty("bar")
    private ValueObject<String> bar;
    @JsonProperty("baz")
    private ValueObject<Integer> baz;

    // potentially we be stretching to have something like
    // private ValueObject<OtherClass> otherObject;
    // but now just the above

    // getters, setters
}

public class ValueObject<T> {
    private static ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    Class<T> containedClass;
    JsonNode value; // This is a requirement to store it as JsonNode
    String otherContext; // This is not in the original json, but something populated after the serialize/deserialization.
    String anotherContext; // This is not in the original json, but something populated after the serialize/deserialization.

    public ValueObject(Class<T> containedClass) {
        this.containedClass = containedClass;
    }


    public T get() {
        return MAPPER.convertValue(this.value, containedClass);
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        if (value.getClass() != containedClass) {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot set value");
        }
        this.value = MAPPER.valueToTree(value);
    }

    // getters, setters
}
```

Sample json

```
{
  "bar": "BAR",
  "baz": 1
}
```

Expected equivalent object

```
Foo expect = new Foo();
ValueObject<String> bar = new ValueObject(String.class);
bar.set("bar");
ValueObject<Integer> baz = new ValueObejct(Integer.class);
baz.set(1);
expected.setBar(bar);
expected.setBaz(baz);
```

Currently, I am thinking of just implementing a CustomSerializer for each ValueObject type, like ValueObjectStringSerializer, ValueObjectIntegerSerializer. Is there another of approaching this?

Comment: The sample JSON is malformed (missing quote after `BAR`)... is that intentional?

Comment: no, thanks for correction

Comment: What's the actual output / error you are seeing?

Comment: I am seeing something like `Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.myname.Playground$ValueObject<java.lang.String>] from String value ('BAR'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: {
 "bar":"BAR",
 "baz":1
};`